# Access string character by index, if index is out of range return ""

Tags: c#

```
var myStr = "hello";
var chars = myStr.Split("");

chars.Select((letter, index) => {
     var nextLetter = myStr[index + 1];
     var nextNextLetter = myStr[index + 2];

     DoSomething(nextLetter, nextNextLetter);
});
```

If give in an index that is larger than length of `myStr` it throws an exception, what I want instead is that it returns `""` when it's out of the index of `myStr`. Is there a string function that can check if given index is in range?

Comment: You mean like `if (myStr.Length < (index + 1))` or something?

Comment: Yes, and also `if (myStr.Length < (index + 2))`

Comment: Well, what's wrong with those two?

Comment: I was wondering if there is a built-in String method that can check at index, without having to create an extension method.

Comment: No, there isn't. But you can always create your own.

Comment: By the way, if you're not aware, you can access `string` as an `IEnumerable<char>` so you could do `myStr.Select((character, index) => ` if you don't mind working with `char` values rather than `string` values.

Comment: @John I didn't know that thanks :)

Comment: With your example you don't need the select and split logic, a normal for loop would be more readable & sufficient: `  for (int i = 0; i < myStr.Length; i++) {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function that will return the value in a safe manner.

```
private char GetValueSafe(string str, int index)
{
   if(index >= str.Length)
   {
      return '\0';
   }
   else 
   {
      return str[index];
   }
  
}
```

And now the usage is simple:

```
var myStr = "hello";
var chars = myStr.Split("");

chars.Select((letter, index) => {
     var nextLetter = GetValueSafe(myStr, index + 1);
     var nextNextLetter = GetValueSafe(myStr,index + 2);

     DoSomething(nextLetter, nextNextLetter);
});
```

Comment: fyi: '' is not a valid char literal, you can use '\0' for the empty char literal

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the index is still in bound. 
You could do something like:

```
var myStr = "hello";
var chars = myStr.Split("");

chars.Select((letter, index) => {
     char nextLetter = '\0';
     char nextNextLetter = '\0';
     if(chars.Length > index){
         nextLetter = myStr[index+1];
         if(chars.Length > index +1)
             nextNextChar = myStr[index+2];
     }

     DoSomething(nextLetter, nextNextLetter);
});
```

Comment: myStr[..] return a `char` and not a `string`.

Comment: again '' is not a valid char literal :), use '\0' or Char.MinValue